# Moto G4(XT1625)Funny behavior with sim card inserted

Tags: motorola-moto-g, sim-card, cellular-radio

I have a Motorola Moto G4(XT1625, Amazon Prime Edition) on US Cellular. Data doesn't work(sim status screen shows connecting or disconnected but never connects), the signal fluctuates somewhat, and occasionally sms and phone temporarily failed for < 5min or so. It is using an older sim card with pronounced contact lines. Would that be a phone problem or a sim card problem, or is additional information needed?

Comment: Get a replacement SIM card. They tend to go bad and symptoms you describe point to that. It happened once with me